# A Question Regarding Markov Chains and Ergodicity

Tags: probability, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, monte-carlo

Suppose the Markov chain with Probability Transition Matrix, $P$ = ($p{_x}{_y}$) is ergodic and $p{_m}(x, y) > 0$ for all states $x$ and $y$.

If $n ≥ m$, show that $p_n(x, y) > 0$ for all states $x$ and $y$.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hint: Fix $(x,y)$, then there exists $z$ such that $p_{n-m}(x,z)\ne0$.

Comment: This means that there is some walk from $x$ to $z$ with positive probability. Then there is some walk from $y$ to $z$ with positive probability? Which means that $p_n(x,y) > 0$?

I am having some trouble understanding ergodicity and its criterion.

Comment: Ergodicity is not needed here. Sub-hint: Can you compare $p_n(x,y)$ and $p_{n-m}(x,z)p_m(z,y)$?

Comment: $p_n(x,y)$ is the probability of getting from state $x$ to state $y$ in $n$ steps and $p_{n-m}(x,z)*p_m(z,y)$ is the probability of going from x to z,which ergodicity implies is positive and then from $z$ to $y$ in $m$ steps. This means there you can get from $x$ to $y$ in $n$ steps with a positive probability. Am I missing or not understanding something?

Comment: No, ergodicity does not imply that $p_{n-m}(x,z)\ne0$. Funny how you seemingly **do not** read my comments...

Comment: Then I'm not understanding it properly. What do you mean to fix $(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you prove that the transition probability for any markov chain is related to its transition matrix?

If, $P^m>0$ obviously $P^n>0$ for all $n\geq m$..? This can be shown as an ergodic markov chain is irreducible. "Did" implied you to use Chapman-Kolmogorov. 
Let, $ p_{zy}^{(m)}>0 $. Then there exists $ p_{xz}^{(n-m)}>0 $ due to irreducibility.

Therefore,
$ p_{xy}^{(n)} = \sum\limits_{k\in E} p_{xk}^{(n-m)} p_{ky}^{(m)} \geq p_{xz}^{(n-m)}p_{zy}^{(m)} > 0  $

Comment: And since $P^m(x,y) > 0$, $P^n(x,y)$ must be greater than 0 as well?

Comment: Yes, what Did wanted you to use was the Chapman Kolmogorov Equation. Wait a sec.

Comment: That sounds far outside the scope of my course. It's undergraduate

Comment: Once, again. Let n = k+m, then ... $P^n = P^{k+m} = P^k P^m >0$ by irreducibility. Check out my edit.

Comment: "That sounds far outside the scope of my course. It's undergraduate" Are we hearing excuses or what?